Como puedo aplicar un linear-gradient al slider?
estoy intentando aplicar este linear-gradient
'linear-gradient(to right, #EDE4FF 0%, #6E4C93 100%)'
a mi slider pero no logro hacerlo, quiero que del lado izquierdo tenga el gradient y del otro sea blanco
me encontre este codigo por ahi pero al momento de cambiar esos colores solidos por el gradient no funciona
input[type="range"] {
   /* removing default appearance */
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   appearance: none; 
   /* creating a custom design */
   width: 100%;
   cursor: pointer;
   outline: none;
   /*  slider progress trick  */
   overflow: hidden;
   border-radius: 16px;
  }

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
   height: 15px;
   background: #ccc;
   border-radius: 16px;
  }

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
   height: 15px;
   background: #ccc;
   border-radius: 16px;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
   /* removing default appearance */
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   appearance: none; 
   /* creating a custom design */
   height: 15px;
   width: 15px;
   background-color: #fff;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border: 2px solid #f50;
   /*  slider progress trick  */
   box-shadow: -407px 0 0 400px #f50;
}
  
  
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
   height: 15px;
   width: 15px;
   background-color: #fff;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border: 1px solid #f50;
   /*  slider progress trick  */
   box-shadow: -407px 0 0 400px #f50;
}

que funcione el linear-gradient

Ya que es código CSS, puedes agregar un snippet (con el botón que indica <>) para poder crear un [repro] en la pregunta misma. No olvides agregar también el HTML en cuestión. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.
